# Losing internet connection after few minutes (5-10 maybe)

Tags: windows-xp, internet

I took a computer that was not updated for months. Internet was working just fine so basically, I updated zonealarm, avast and installed all windows updates and especially SP3. After that, when I reboot, Internet works fine but **after few minutes, Firefox says that the connection was reset**. IE does not work either. However, my connection is still up and running as **I can make a ping on www.google.com** for example. Here are the solutions I tried with no success so far:

1) Uninstalling SP3;

2) Uninstalling IE8 and IE7;

3) Manually setting DNS and IPs;

4) Removed proxy settings from Firefox and IE;

5) Restarting DNS and DHCP related services;

6) Reset TCP/IP with netsh int ip reset c:\resetlog.txt;

7) Updated my ehternet card driver;

8) Restarted, tweaked all the connections in any directions and any configuration possible I believe;

9) Disabled Zone Alarm and Avast;

Also, **update kb981793 always fails on install**.

Please, help me as I spent two days already on this and I cannot find any solution. If I cannot fix this problem tomorrow, **I will have to format-reinstall everything**.

Thanks for any help.

Regards.

Comment: Has the network card driver been updated? Sometimes, a new driver can be flaky and cause the machine to drop the network connection.

Comment: Yes, see point 7.

Comment: I'd be willing to bet that the problem is with ZoneAlarm (ZA makes me sad `:(`).

Comment: Well, I disabled it and no difference...

Comment: are you 100% sure there is no problem from ISP side?

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this behaviour before on machines.  Both cases it turned out to be ZoneAlarm.  Not sure why those specific machines and not others.  Very strange.

Comment: I completely disabled it. No change...;(

Comment: I had to remove it, disabling didn't help.  It appears to stick something into the system that interferes, whether running or not.

Comment: No change... I finally reinstalledt everything.

Answer (score 1):

Just a shot in the dark, but, clear your DNS cache and use some alternate DNS server(e.g. 8.8.8.8 which is google's own DNS server)